# find links in a text and wrap that in a tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am pulling tweets using a twitter API and assigning it into a variable. LIke so.

```
        self.tweets = $.map(data.results, function(tweet){
                return{
                    author: tweet.from_user,
                    url: 'http://twitter.com/' + tweet.from_user + '/status/' + tweet.id_str,
                    image: tweet.profile_image_url,
                    tweet: tweet.text
                };
            });
```

I works for me. and I am appending the tweet to HTML. the text is like so..

```
 @drwarwick Hi David! Looking forward to catching up with you, but may not get in there today due to work commitments...
```

What I want to do now is wrap the @drwarwick into a @drwarwick so that I can style and link it accordingly. How do I find uisng jquery any such words in the tweets. Thanks.

EDIT>>>>>

something like stackoverflow is doing above. It has changed the color of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote a helper method to do that.

```
function HighLight(input)
{
    var output="";
    var items=input.split(" ");
    $.each(items,function(index,item){
       var word=items[index];
       if(word.match("^@"))
       {
           word="<span class='highlightSpan'>"+word+"</span>";  
       }                         
       output+=word+" ";
    });    
    return output;
}
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/ZSafX/27/

You can change your code to include that like this

```
    self.tweets = $.map(data.results, function(tweet){
            return{
                author: tweet.from_user,
                url: 'http://twitter.com/' + tweet.from_user + '/status/' + tweet.id_str,
                image: tweet.profile_image_url,
                tweet: HighLight(tweet.text)
            };
        });
```

Comment: that does help. But for me the tweets are being loaded via AJAX. so this code is running before the tweets are being loaded. so when this function runs there is no text at all in DOM, if I am right.

Comment: @Subash: I believe we added the Highlight function call while processing your request from the ajax request. So it should be good to go.